# Editing Label from another Class (Java FX)

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

i have got a question:
i have got a simple Java FX Application where i have a button and when i hit the button a thread task starts which have to change a label every second:

MyController.java

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;


public class MyController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private Button myButton;
    @FXML
    private TextField myCountry;
    @FXML
    public Label myTime;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void startTimeThread(ActionEvent event) {
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor eventPool =  new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(3);
        eventPool.scheduleAtFixedRate
        (new CheckSystemTime(), 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        myButton.setDisable(true);
    }

    public void setLabel(String text) {
        myTime.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Main.java is the standart one

CheckSystemTime.java

```
package application;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;


public class CheckSystemTime implements Runnable  {

    //String locale;

    public CheckSystemTime(/**String location**/) {
        //this.locale = location;
    }

    public void run() {

        Date rightNow;
        DateFormat timeFormatter;
        String timeOutput;

        rightNow = new Date();
        Locale currentLocale = new Locale("de");

        timeFormatter = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, currentLocale);
        timeOutput = timeFormatter.format(rightNow);

        //e.g. MyController.setLabel(timeOutput); doesnt work   
    }
}
```

So my question is, how i am able to access the setLabel Method from the CheckSystemTime class?
i hope you are able to help me how i can solve this problem

Comment: In your `MyController.java` you call `eventPool.scheduleAtFixedRate` with `new Main()`. This should probably be `new CheckSystemTime()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `MyController` or a `Label` or the `textProperty` of the `Label` to the constructor of `CheckSystemTime`. Then you can keep a local reference inside `CheckSystemTime`. Then you can access it inside your run method. But make sure to wrap every UI related calls inside `Platform.runLater()`.